# Is it a bad idea to make ef core DbContext transient?

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

I have multiple IHostedService instances and each instance according to the time when it springs to action should use DbContext to perform some database works.

Should I use scoped, transient or singleton in this case ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It rly comes down to design and architecture, but i would suggest always going on the "Scoped" route.

This will make sure that each new request will receive a new context, but the same context will be used for the same request, meaning that you start to get a "transactional" type of request serving, which is the best thing to do on 99% of the business cases.

If there is a request that i.e:

1. Assignes a new vehicle to the user
2. Charches the user's account

then you want the whole business logic within your server request to be "transactional" in respect to the changes of the data. Either both changes will succeed and commit as part of the "business transaction" or non will, leaving you with a clean data-set.

Having them "Transient" risks many concurrency related stuff, especcialy because we are talking for EF context.

Having them "Singleton" could be ok, again with the general architecture of the application and proper handling of dependency injections in mind.

Comment: Transient has the issue that you can't pass EF-tracked object between services then that rely on different context instances, change tracking doesn't quite work then. Singleton usually can't be used since a context owns a connection to the DB and multiple requests attempting to use the same connection leads to errors. Scoped is kinda the natural choice usually (and the reason why it is default).

Comment: I tried not to over-detail stuff, but in general you are correct, transient are nono, and singleton is actually feasible, but requires more understanding and setup in comparisson with the "Scoped" one